# Hosting and application on local IIS

Tags: iis, localhost, iis-7.5

I have an application which I can access from my own computer using the following url:

`http://188.24.7.228/PetitionsApp/`

But this fails if I try to access it from other computers. Is there a setting in IIS to allow me to host the app like this?

If I am able to access the webpage like `http://188.24.7.228/PetitionsApp/`, shouldn't others be able to as well?

**EDIT:**

I am running Windows 7, IIS 7.5.

Comment: What version of IIS?  What version of windows?  Can other computers ping the server?  Are they all on the same network?

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall settings, the default TCP port for HTTP requests is 80. If you are not sure about how configuring the firewall, you can disable it for a quick test.

**EDIT**
Some additional comments:

1) If your firewall is ON and using the default settings, probably the answer is **no**, they will not be able to reach you while you don't set a rule to open the port 80 or free the IIS itself.

2) Since the other computers seems to be in your local network, have you tried using your local IP address?

3) Your IP address seems to be a valid internet IP, so at least here in Brazil, the majority of ISPs block the port 80, so people can't create home servers. In this case, you should try using another port (ex: 8080), which can be configured in IIS through the *Site Bindings* option.